# How to query 1 table with 6 columns with condition in 3 of the columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

All I'm trying to do is a query for my table that contains 6 columns with a condition that has to be met by 3 of those columns

my table's information 
table name My_table columns a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6

the code I have tried is below, doesn't work of course

```
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM My_table WHERE a2='$variable1' AND a3='$variable2' AND a6='$variable3' ORDER BY a2 ASC";
$myresult = mysql_query($myquery);
```

my result has to contain the rows that met the conditions above.

What is the right way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Blind SQL injection here we come... I hope you escape `$variableN`.

Comment: @rekire Can you help me or not?

Comment: I'm not sure the SQL statment itself seems to be correct...

Comment: @rekire is it possible to use two AND conditions inside WHERE?

Comment: See this here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db4ff/1/0 that works fine... Yes you can use so much `and`s and `or`s like you want.

Comment: Don't use mysql_XXX functions in new code. Please use mysqli_XXX or PDO, and use prepared statements to substitute parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is how I made it work, it works great for me so it could help you too.

Since I'm comparing 3 columns of my table with 3 variables and I know that they are fix and has to meet those conditions exactly and in that order, I made a string of the 3 columns I'm searching in UPPER case then did the same with my variables then compare the against each other, that gave me the result I was looking for.

here is the solution code to my problem:

```
$myquery = "SELECT a2 a3 a6 FROM My_table WHERE concat(UPPER(a2), UPPER(a3), UPPER(a6)) LIKE concat(UPPER('$variable1'), UPPER('$variable2'), UPPER('$variable3')) ORDER BY a2 ASC";
```

$myresult = mysql_query($myquery);

Hopes it helps someone else too.

Comment: Why don't you use `WHERE a2 LIKE '$variable1' AND a3 LIKE '$variable2' AND a6 LIKE '$variable3'` if you want case-insensitive comparison?

Comment: @ypercube I tried so many things and didn't work, I don't know if I try that one, the one I wrote here in my answer is working, but thanks for sharing that option too.

Answer (score 2):

Missing:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($myresult);
```

You can use the following naming convention to avoid this kind of errors:

```
$my_sql = "SELECT * FROM My_table WHERE a2='$variable1' AND a3='$variable2' AND a6='$variable3' ORDER BY a2 ASC";
$my_query = mysql_query($my_sql);
$my_result = mysql_fetch_array($my_query);
```

Comment: @ypercube the ORDER BY a2 ASC does works because at the moment I display the results I want them to show up in that columns alphabetical order.